# Robot Framework anchor tag value is not retrieved

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
<div class="m-page-nav m-bottom-2" data-hbui="mobile-nav" role="navigation">
<span aria-`enter code here`label="Collapse page navigation" class="a-icon m-page-nav-icon m-page-nav-icon-collapse">expand_more</span>
<span aria-label="Expand page navigation" class="a-icon m-page-nav-icon m-page-nav-icon-expand">expand_more</span>
<button data-scroll-header class="m-page-nav-button"></button>
<div data-gumshoe class="m-page-nav-list">
<a data-scroll href="#intro" tabindex="0">Intro</a>
<a data-scroll href="#courseHeadingDescription" tabindex="0">Enrolment Disclaimer</a>
<a data-scroll href="#admissionRequirements" tabindex="0">Admission Requirements</a>
<a data-scroll href="#programRequirements" tabindex="0">Program Requirements</a>
<a data-scroll href="#professionalOutcomes" tabindex="0">Professional Outcomes</a>
<a data-scroll href="#recognitionMasters" tabindex="0">Recognition of Achievement</a>
<a data-scroll href="#fees" tabindex="0">Program Fees</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I am kind of new to robot framework. I am trying to retrieve the value from the `href` anchor tag value that is `Intro` using the following xpath

```
//*[@id="pageNavContainer"]/div/div/a[2]/@href
```

But when I run the script to get the text with the above xpath I am getting the below error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath express
```

I tried using `getattribute` also but it didn't work.
Can anyone please help me out what is the correct xpath for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: *I tried using getattribute also but it dint work*.. Share this code also

Comment: I don't see anything with an id of `pageNavContainer` in the html example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **Intro** you can use the following `xpath` :

```
//*[@id="pageNavContainer"]//div[@class='m-page-nav m-bottom-2']//div[@class='m-page-nav-list']//following-sibling::a[1]
```

Next you can use the **Get Element Attribute** to extract the `href` :

```
${HREF}=    Get Element Attribute    ${element_xpath}@href
```

Comment: That's quite an xpath... 1st, it won't return the first element, as is its probable intent  - due to the precedence of `//` and `[],` **and** the use of `following-sibling`. It will return all `a` nodes. To get the 1st one with it, parentheses must be used: `(//*[@id="pageNavContainer"]//div[@class='m-page-nav m-bottom-2']//div[@class='m-page-nav-list']//following-sibling::a)[1]`

Comment: Also, it's too complicated for its own good - I see what you're trying to do with the usage of `following-sibling`,but it changes the nodeset just before the positional prerogative and thus leads to the unexpected evaluation result.And using the `//` operator in a direct parent-child structure is suboptimal. This is a bit simplified version - `//*[@id="pageNavContainer"]/div[@class='m-page-nav m-bottom-2']//div[@class='m-page-nav-list']/a[1]` - note the lack of `()`,and the position works as expected. Please note - I'm not trying to nitpick,just liked your expression - it caught my attention:)

Answer (score 0):

The error you received says it all - the selector you provided is not a valid one; the problem comes from the `/@href` construct at the end.

In XPath one can for sure address a particular node's attribute with this syntax. Yet in Selenium (which Robotframework wraps), a locator has to point to an element, not its attribute - thus when it evaluates your expression, it throws the exception.

If you change the locator to

```
//*[@id="pageNavContainer"]/div/div/a[2]
```

, and the use `Get Element Attribute` passing href as the target, you'll get the desired value.

Comment: Thanks guys i got the solution    xpath=//*[@id="pageNavContainer"]/div/div/a[position() = 1 and @href]    this worked for me

Comment: OK; that xpath is "get the a with that position, which has an `href` attribute"